# Simulating the URDF and sending commands

Tags: urdf, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have been working with the [URDF tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) on the ROS website and have created a simplified version of my humanoid robot in the .urdf format.

I have been able to visual the robot and add some physical and collision properties. Now I want to automatically simulate the robot moving its joints by sending it some commands over the messaging service. Where can I learn how to do this?

Kind Regards,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52506/simulating-the-urdf-and-sending-commands/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Start here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/CreatingASpinningTopInGazebo

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2013-01-16**:
Thanks davinci, this tutorial will help a lot! I was wondering if you knew the significance of start_time: 10000000000? Why the huge number for start_time, couldn't I just set the start_time at 0?